# Moq which Version to use

Tags: moq

I am starting a new project and I would like to know which version of Moq should I be using?
I have noticed that there is a version 4? Is that RTM?

In my place there are a bit funny  about beta versions?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the currently featured download (4.0.10827) is release;  Version 4.0.10818 was the last version labeled as a beta on the [downloads list](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is the link broken.Cannot seem to get there.

Comment: @user231465, the link works for me, but you can also get there by going to the [moq site](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), then go to the Downloads section.  In the Search drop down list, choose 'All Downloads', don't enter anything in 'for', and click Search.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks used firefox and was ok.IE 9 beta was cause of the problem